# Uso de close en Python

Tags: python, archivo

¿Por qué es necesario cerrar (**close**) un archivo (**file**) abierto (**open**) en Python? ¿Qué sucedería en caso de dejar abierto el archivo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dependiendo de la versión de Python que estés usando, el archivo será cerrado cuando deje de referenciarse, o se cerrará más adelante (cuando pase el recolector de basura), o puede que nunca se cierre... y eso puede dar lugar a algunos problemas:

- **Puedes perder datos**: si el fichero se ha abierto en modo escritura, algunos de los cambios puede que no se guarden o hagan efectivos hasta que el archivo sea cerrado. Por lo que si no cierras el archivo, podrías perder datos si el programa termina de forma inesperada.
- **Puedes perder la habilidad de abrir archivos**: el sistema operativo limita el número de archivos que pueden abrirse al mismo tiempo. Si tu programa trabaja con muchos archivos y no los cierras después de abrirlos, pueden acumularse abiertos y llegar al límite establecido, haciendo que el programa acabe fallando.
- **El programa puede ralentizarse**: los archivos abiertos ocupan espacio en memoria y ocupan recursos del sistema, el no cerrarlos puede acabar afectando al rendimiento y la velocidad de tu programa.
- **Los archivos pueden bloquearse**: por ejemplo en Windows, cuando un archivo se abre, se bloquea y no puede operarse con él hasta que éste sea cerrado (el típico error de "la operación no se puede realizar porque el fichero está en uso").
- **Pierdes control del programa**: al no cerrar los archivos abiertos, dependes de que Python y el recolector de basura los cierren por ti, y no sabes cuándo o cómo va a ocurrir eso. Al cerrarlos tú mismo ganas control sobre tu programa y hace tu programación más robusta y portable.

No estoy diciendo que todos esos problemas vayan a ocurrir pero, con que ocurra alguno de ellos, su impacto podría ser muy negativo en tu aplicación. Es por eso que es importante (y se considera una buena práctica) cerrar los archivos una vez hayas terminado de trabajar con ellos.

Comment: Como comentarios, esto no sería algo exclusivo de Python: algunos de los puntos expuestos arriba también aplicarían en otros lenguajes de programación.

Comment: Gracias por tan ilustrativa respuesta, @Alvaro Montoro. Tu comentario ha iluminado y respondido más de una duda para mi, en realidad; y en el futuro lo tendré muy en cuenta al trabajar con archivos... y como bien dices, no solo en Python... Muy agradecido. Saludos!